# Why does Safari frequently log me out of websites?

Tags: safari, login, cookies

Recently, Safari started to act differently and to bounce me out from websites such as Gmail, so I need to login after reboot or long sleep etc.

Why is this happening? How do I make Safari "remember" I'm logged in?

Comment: macOS Version ?

Comment: Latest and greatest: High Sierra -- 10.13.5 (17F77)

Comment: Have you by any chance opened a private window in Safari by accident?

Comment: you don't have this problem @jksoegaard? not using private windows.

Comment: No, haven't got that problem at all.

Comment: Have you tried disabling "Prevent cross-site tracking" in Safari in the Privacy tab in preferences?

Comment: macOS Catalina has finally resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [seems](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/afu0rv/since_macos_mojave_safari_logs_me_out_from/) [to](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOSBeta/comments/8t49sa/bug_safari_keeps_logging_me_out_of_websites/) [be](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2389095) [a](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/104851) common issue (which I also experience). I know that Safari is particular with how it handles cookies, which is a likely cause. I'm assuming this is on Apple's radar.

I have some suspicion that it's because I have website tracking completely off, but never tested it fully as I prefer to have it off.

As a temporary fix, the use of a password manager ([iCloud Keychain](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204085) is built into Apple devices) makes the login process faster.